# PostgreSQL: getting error messages from `pg_convert()`

Tags: php, postgresql, error-handling

I'm trying to diagnose a problem only found on a production system and I'm trying to improve the error reporting for errors thrown by `pg_convert()`, but not sure where to go. I tried changing the code in the dev environment to:

```
$converted_values = pg_convert($cnx, $table, $values);
if ($converted_values === FALSE)
    throw new Exception("Failed to insert record: '".pg_last_error($cnx)."' using values: ".var_export($values, true));
```

But `pg_last_error()` returned nothing.

Note: I tested the above by trying to insert a null value into a `NOT NULL` column. In addition to getting no joy from `pg_last_error()` the log had some "PHP Notice"s in it. The production log didn't have any such notices. Just the empty return value from `pg_convert()` :(

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4.6 on Debian 8.3 and PHP 5.6.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, trying to get anything done w/`pg_convert()` is a bust. It's not very reliable in dealing w/different data, and it's inconsistent about putting double quotes around column names. If you're using `pg_convert()` you'll likely want to convert to prepared statements. What they do is very different, so you might have to make fundamental changes to your code base, but we made the change and it seems to be working for us.

Edit: and one such problem that `pg_convert()`/`pg_query()` seemed to be able to roll w/that `pg_execute()` doesn't, is empty strings assigned to integer columns where `NOT NULL` isn't set. To fix this (at least for now) I had to:

- loop through the array passed to `pg_execute()`
- call `pg_meta_data()` when I found one w/an empty string
- determine if the destination column is an integer (be careful: there are probably a lot of ways in which the type for an integer column can be expressed) then if nulls are allowed at all
- overwrite the empty string w/null.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a NULL into a NOT NULL column will not trigger an error in pg_convert. Errors will result from connection problems, a missing table, or a missing column, or data that cannot be converted from the PHP structure to the type in the database (e.g. a word to a number).

Comment: It did for me. `pg_convert()` returned `FALSE`. Taking away that one field not only removed the notices about the type being incompatible but also the `FALSE` return value.